# haxe - Comparison of enums and strict order

Tags: enums, compare, haxe

I have a enum type:

```
enum HandRank {
    HighCard;
    OnePair;
    Set;
    TwoPair;
    Straight;
    Flush;
    FullHouse;
    Quads;
    StraightFlush;
    RoyalFlush;
}
```

And I'd like to compare a pair of values to choose a better one. Something like:

```
maxRank = <...some method...>(firstRank, secondRank) ? firstRank : secondRank;
```

Here I suppose that all values of enum follow in prefferable ascending order. What should I do to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
maxRank = Type.enumIndex(firstRank) > Type.enumIndex(secondRank) ? firstRank : secondRank;
```

Answer (score 1):

i would write a max function like this:

```
class HandRanks {
    public static function toInt (a:HandRank) return switch a {
        case HighCard: 1;
        case OnePair: 2;
        case Set: 3;
        case TwoPair: 4;
        case Straight: 5;
        case Flush: 6;
        case FullHouse: 7;
        case Quads: 8;
        case StraightFlush: 9;
        case RoyalFlush: 10;
    }
    public static function max (a:HandRank, b:HandRank) {
        var a1 = toInt(a);
        var b1 = toInt(b);
        return if (a1 > b1) a else b;
    }
}

// usage
using HandRanks;
HighCard.max(Set); // Set
```